# Type hinting and void return question

Tags: php, customization

Say I have a class that registers a custom post type like

```
class Test {
  /**
   * The custom post type slug
   *
   * @var string
   *
   * @since 1.0.0
   */
  const POST_TYPE_SLUG = 'test';

  /**
   * Register custom post type
   *
   * @since 1.0.0
   */
  public function register_test_post_type() {
    $args = array(
        'label'              => esc_html( 'Test', 'my-test' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'menu_position'      => 50,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'revisions' ),
        'has_archive'        => false,
        'show_in_rest'       => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'can_export'         => true,
    );

    register_post_type( self::POST_TYPE_SLUG, $args );
  }
}
```

I am wondering if it's good to use return type `void` in this case when I'm using the method as a callback function in a hook

```
$test = new Test();

add_action( 'init',  [ $test, 'register_test_post_type' ] );
```

Especially since [register_post_type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/), as written in the docs will return

> (WP_Post_Type|WP_Error) The registered post type object, or an error object.

In this case, should I set the return type to `WP_Post_Type` or `void`?

```
public function register_test_post_type() : void {}
```

or

```
public function register_test_post_type() : WP_Post_Type {}
```

I'm working with PHP 7.1, so `void` typehinting is ok.

Another thing that is a bit confusing - every time I have an action hook that does something like in the case of `pre_get_posts`, but doesn't return anything, is it ok to put the return type as a `void`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback functions for an*action* hook don't need to return anything, so based on the description [here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php):

> A void return type has been introduced. Functions declared with void
>   as their return type must either omit their return statement
>   altogether, or use an empty return statement. NULL is not a valid
>   return value for a void function.

`void` would be appropriate in this context. Note that your `register_test_post_type()` method does not actually return the value of `register_post_type()`. So while `register_post_type()` might return a post type object, your function doesn't.

Comment: Ok, thanks for setting my mind at ease (plus I don't have to rewrite tons of void return type hints in my code :D). I'll accept the answer in 8 min :)